# How to handle the addValueEventListener from firebase's realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that sends data to a firebase realtime database. Another app takes the data from the database and displays it in an activity. I use the addValueEventListener so that whenever there's new data added, the second app shows it. The data is basically a name and a phone number. The problem is that when i am on the activity that displays the data and i enter data from the other app the activity crashes, because of a null pointer exception. After some logs i have discovered that the problem is that the name field is in the snapshot but the phone field is not. The database is correctly updated, so i think the problems is the fact that the second app takes data too fast from the database and does not wait for it all to be added to the database. Is this the problem? How can i solve this problem?

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot s: snapshot.getChildren()){
                         Button rent = createButton(s.child("Name").getValue().toString(), s.child("Phone").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    }

@Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
Log.i("ERROR",":C");
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem. The first app was adding the name first in the database and after the phone number. The idea is to add them together like an object.
eg. {"Name" : "Mike", "Phone":"82741241"}. This way you don't get the null pointer exception because the app adds both the name and phone and does not add first the name and triggers the addValueEventListener in the second app with an missing phone field.